# Vertical Scroll in TabLayout

Tags: android, xml

I have a collapsing toolbar with an image in, as well as a TabLayout using a viewpager. I need to be able to scroll inside the Tablayout per fragment as well as collapse the toolbar when i scroll the content up.

Layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/listing_root_coordinator"
                                                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                     tools:context=".item.ItemActivity">


      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

          <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
              android:id="@+id/toolBar_image"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="256dp"
              android:scaleType="centerCrop"
              app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/listings_toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
              app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap">


          <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
              android:id="@+id/listing_tab_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:isScrollContainer="true"
              android:paddingTop="16dp"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
              app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
              app:tabMode="scrollable"
              app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
              app:tabTextColor="#EEE"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/listing_view_pager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>


      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:id="@+id/item_activity_add_to_watchlist_fab"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="8dp"
          android:src="@drawable/watch"
          app:fabSize="mini"
          app:layout_anchor="@id/listing_tab_layout"
          app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"/>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/item_activity_is_hot_icon"
          android:layout_width="32dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingBottom="32dp"
          android:paddingLeft="8dp"
          android:src="@drawable/hot"
          android:visibility="gone"
          app:layout_anchor="@id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
          app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"/>


      <ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/item_activity_progress_bar"
          style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I can scroll fine when i touch in the toolbar, the image and the tabs in the tablayout, but when i try scroll up in the content(which is a fragment) the screen does not respond to my touch. Although i am able to scroll left and right in the tabs to go to each tab.

Please help me enabling the user to be able to scroll vertical no matter where the touch is?

Thank you